# Understanding Lists : Syntax and Passing Arguments

Tags: c#, list

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding lists in C# and was hoping someone could help me understand.

I have been following several tutorials as I try to learn, but I got there are two points that have me a bit confused.

The first question that I have was understanding the parameters being passed in the elements in the list.

```
("fire", 5)
("static", 3)
```

I understand the first, but what do the integers following the string represent?

My second question is based on the final line:

```
powerUps RandomPowerup = powerUpsList[Random.Range(0, powerUpsList.Count)]
```

I'm being told that...

> powerUpsList
>   ...does not exist in the context.

I understand the meaning of the message but do not understand how this could be. My guess is that I have left out a syntax, but I do not quite understand where at.

Here is the entire code for context.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class powerUpList : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        List<powerUps> powerUpsList = new List<powerUps>();

        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("fire", 5));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("static", 3));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("shield", 0));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("repel", 0));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("repairKit", 0));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("thorns", 3));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("bearBooster", 1));

        powerUpsList.Sort();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider player)
    {
        powerUps RandomPowerup = powerUpsList[Random.Range(0, powerUpsList.Count)];
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help, insights, or suggestions you could give me.

Comment: 1. The integer is simple the 2nd argument for the `constructor` for the `class` `powerUps`
2. Press `CTRL +.`, and then `enter` and see for yourself

Comment: the powerUpsList should be outside of Start method. Because you define powerUpsList inside that method, it will exist only for that method (variable scope)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the definition of the `powerUps` class, we would not be able to tell you what the number after the string is for. You are calling the constructor on the `powerUp` class, so you will need to refer to that to understand what it is used for.

For the second part, you create the list of powerups withing the `Start()` function. Once that function returns, that list no longer exists. To fix this, you need to make `powerUpsList` a class variable. This should work:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class powerUpList : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<powerUps> powerUpsList;

    void Start()
    {
        powerUpsList = new List<powerUps>();

        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("fire", 5));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("static", 3));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("shield", 0));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("repel", 0));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("repairKit", 0));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("thorns", 3));
        powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("bearBooster", 1));

        powerUpsList.Sort();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider player)
    {
        powerUps RandomPowerup = powerUpsList[Random.Range(0, powerUpsList.Count)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of your sample:

```
powerUpsList = new List<powerUps>();
powerUpsList.Add(new powerUps("fire", 5));
```

This does *three* things. It could be written like this:

```
powerUpsList = new List<powerUps>(); // create an empty list 
powerup foo = new powerUps("fire", 5); // create a powerUp object
powerUpsList.Add(foo); // put the object in the list
```

This `new powerUp("fire", 5)` is a constructor invocation. What the parameters mean is a question that can only be answered by the documentation for the code that defines the powerUp class. Taking a wild stab in the dark, 5 is the number of seconds this power up confers fire magic in your game.